# In Java, can you call a setter for one class inside a constructor for another class?

Tags: java, constructor, setter, getter

If you have two classes **Boo** and **Foo**, and each Instance of **Foo** contains in it an instance of **Boo**, can you have a *Setter* for a private attribute in **Boo** contained inside in the *constructor* of **Foo**?

Comment: As a matter of fact, generally it is better to call the getters/setters instead of setting the variables directly.

Comment: On your revised Student class you should be invoking `this.name.setFirstName()` not `Name.setFirstName()` the former is attempting to invoke a method (setter) on a particular object, whereas the latter is attempting to invoke a static method on the Name class.

Comment: In the Name class should I remove the parameters from the Constructor as the next step? The class compiles when I do this but I'm not sure I fully understand the logic behind how the Name class works anymore. Now when a Name object is initiated from within the Student class the constructor will run but there are no parameters for it to set firstName and lastName with so I don't understand how the construtor runs without an error?

Comment: Normally fields are set to their default values. As String is an object and not a primitive type (although a special one) the field values would be set to `null`. This is probably not for the best as a `null` value would indicate that the object is in an illegal state - that is, if any Name instance must contain both a first name and a last name. If this is the case, leave the constructor as it is.

Comment: What you should not do is call getters or setters of the `this` instance from the constructor; if they are overridden you may get strange behaviour (Effective Java 2nd edition, item #17). It's perfectly fine to call getters/setters of other instances, it's even recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Why would you not be able to?

```
class Boo {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Foo {
    private final Boo boo;

    public Foo() {
        boo = new Boo();
        boo.setName("boo");
    }
}
```

The fact that you ask the question suggests there's something you *think* might go wrong - what in particular did you have in mind?

Comment: I had been advised not to do it, but I don't see a problem in doing it. I'm new to coding so I just wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @user1577173 You better listen to God.

Comment: @user1577173: When someone suggests that you don't do something, you should ask them for reasons why. It's possible that what you were advised wasn't *really* what you've represented here - but in any case, if you understand the reasons behind advice, it makes it a lot easier to apply it more widely.

Comment: Ah, huh, sorry. Did not expect that as I didn't see a question in there. Removing my comments, you may want to do same.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is to try it out yourself.

It is not hard to test and see the results in this case.

How else can your learn how to program if not by doing it?

Comment: Thanks. I've posted revised code in the original comment. I think I'm going in the right direction but I havn't been able to get it to compile again yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I can't see any problem about it.

EDIT:

Uncomment your code. Your getter/setters are just fine.

Comment: I've edited my code and uncommented the setters and I'm trying to edit my code to allow me to use them properly but the code is no longer compiling. I've edited my initial comment to include the revised code. Do I need to edit the parameters in the Name constructor if I'm using a setter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your new code is here:

```
    this.name = new Name();
    Name.setFirstName(firstName);
    Name.setLastName(lastName);
```

`Name` is a class name. In order for `Name.setFirstName()` to be a valid call, `setFirstName()` would have to be a static method in `Name`.  Presumably it is an instance method instead.  You need to invoke it for a specific instance of the class, in this case the one referred to by `this.name`.  So the correct code would be:

```
    this.name = new Name();
    this.name.setFirstName(firstName);
    this.name.setLastName(lastName);
```

Back to your original question -- my guess is that the advice you were given not to call setters from your constructor was based on an idea along the lines of "constructors should not have side effects".  In this case, you are constructing a brand new `Name` object to be a part of your new `Student`, so it is perfectly appropriate to make any calls you need to initialize the object.

However, I don't see why you would prefer this to calling `Name`'s constructor.  Fewer lines, and the whole thing either succeeds or doesn't.

Comment: thanks. that makes sense. In the `Name` class should I remove the parameters from the Constructor as the next step? The class compiles when I do this but I'm not sure I fully understand the logic behind how the `Name` class works anymore. Now when a `Name` object is initiated from within the `Student` class the constructor will run but there are no parameters for it to set `firstName` and `lastName` with so I don't understand how the construtor runs without an error?

Comment: Again, I don't understand why you would prefer (A) calling a no-argument constructor then the setters, over (B) calling a two-argument constructor that sets the members.  Generally, you want the constructor do do everything that makes an instance of the class useful.  What use is a `Name` object without values for the `firstName` and `lastName` members?

Comment: When you invoke `Name()`, it is not calling the two-argument constructor that you wrote in your code.  Every class has a default no-argument constructor that does nothing.  In this case, I would suggest that a `Name` with no values is a useless construct, so you should not use that constructor.  You can even prevent it from being used by explicitly declaring it `private`.